# What's the meaning of キレてるよ?

Tags: translation, slang, song-lyrics, anime

In the [opening song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgympfbOgqw) of the anime 「ダンベル何キロ持てる？」, the phrase 「キレてるよ！」 can be heard e.g. at 00:12 in the linked video. According to [this website](https://www.lyrical-nonsense.com/lyrics/hibiki-sakura-naruzou-machio/onegai-muscle/), it gets translated as "You're doing it!". However, according to [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%20%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AC%E3%82%8B), the meaning should rather be "I'm angry" (or something like that). How do I make sense of the 「キレてるよ！」 in the song?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's bodybuilders' slang. Japanese bodybuilding fans somehow use [unique ways of praising someone's muscles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKAIpQ37MP0), and キレてるよ is one of the most common. This キレてる describes a well-developed and "separated" muscle with little subcutaneous fat, such as six-pack abs. I think this is from [カット](https://bodymakingtips.com/2017/05/30/bodybuilding-words/#i-2), another term that refers to beautiful separation of muscles after losing subcutaneous fat.

See:

- [キレてる (きれてる)とは【ピクシブ百科事典】](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AC%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B)
- [A video of real competition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmS2Fmn0BZo) (You can hear キレてるよ yelled by the audience)